# What happens when you take a whole monthly dose of zinc just once per month?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, risks, supplement, zinc, missed-dose

When it comes to Vitamin D3 supplementation there are [studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15251658) that give a patient a big dose of 50,000 UI once per month. What happens when I take a similar approach to supplementing zinc?
Are there adverse effects from taking too much on a single day?

Answer (score 3):

That approach works with some supplements and not others. Iron, for example, will be held in the small intestine until the blood level lowers enough for safe absorption by which time it might just be pushed out of the body.

Zing is regulated by secretions in urine and sweat. Any you ingest, or breath in (unsafe welding practices), will be absorbed by the blood stream in a rather reckless fashion. Then the body will filter it down to normal levels. Before your body accomplishes this task you might be subjected to symptoms of zinc poisoning. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_toxicity

Comment: might add that A,D,E,and K vitamins are fat soluble, so your body holds onto them longer.  Yes D can be taken like that, but that is not usually indicated unless there's deficiency.  Vitamins and minerals are cofactors and enzyme components and all sorts of things in your body. You CAN overdose on many of them.